# Is their a way by which I can embed the javascript inside the GWT code?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

final HTML statushHTML = new HTML(" ", true);

statushHTML.setHTML(result);

// in result i am passing string

```
1. result = <b> bold </b>   // it displays bold
2. result = <i> italics </i> // it works
3. result = <font color='red'> red </font>  // it works again
4. result = <h1> h1 tag </h1> // this also works fine

But if i try

5. result = <script> alert('No output') </script> // now it doesn't work


It's just displaying it in string format.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert script use [`ScriptInjector`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html).

Example code:

```
String script = "alert('No output')";
ScriptInjector.fromString(script).inject();
```

Comment: well i am trying to send a rpc call from client side and returning the response from server side in form of string but it's reading other tag not the script tag , i tried using ScriptInjector as told by Adam but I am getting this error

com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.customer.phone.client.CustomerService.userValidation(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gwt.core.client.ScriptInjector

Comment: do i need to change my approach ??